# Kafka Stream Window on Geolocation Point

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to exploit the Kafka Stream library to perform a streaming analysis with a session window, but I'd like the "session window" not be evaluated on time, but on a geo-distance metric.

I've tried to look for it on internet but couldn't find any resources, does anyone know about something? Just in case I've missed something before starting changing the class.

**Edit**

I'd like something as:

at the time T0 arrives the message:

```
{
tm: T0
lat: x
lon: y
}
```

at the time T1 > T0:

```
{
tm: T1
lat: x + Delta_x
lon: y + Delta_y
}
```

I would like to define a "session window" over both the coordinates and the time, if the new message arrive in an appropriate time window and in an appropriate "coordinate distance" the session goes on, if one of those policy is missing you close the session window

**End of the edit**

Thanks
Matteo

Comment: By definition, a session has events within a time window, though. Can you give an example of inputs and expected output?

Comment: Thanks. What research into session windows have you already done, and why aren't they suitable for you? Explicitly because of the "idle time" constraints?